# Object Traversing from specific Point

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am preloading images in my code . i want to traverse only first five object , how can I do that?

Can I start traversing Object from some particular point length?

http://jsfiddle.net/pvuvkzgt/

Code:

```
for (var key in detailes_obj) {
    if (detailes_obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // do something with albums[key]
        console.log(detailes_obj[key].poster);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid you need to make a count variable outside of the for loop like so:

```
var count = 0;
for (var key in detailes_obj) {
    if (detailes_obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && count < 5) {
        // do something with albums[key]
        console.log(detailes_obj[key].poster);
        count++;
    }
}
```

[Updated your fiddle as well](http://jsfiddle.net/ostrgard/pvuvkzgt/1/)

Comment: The relevancy of your comment is entirely up to the specific use case. Given the information OP have provided in the question, along with the object in the fiddle, I would say my answer is solving the issue. If not, he/she is more than welcome to comment.

EDIT: As for your simplification - why not just post it as an answer?